# Python GTK 3+ controlling closing the window

Tags: python, linux, windows, gtk3

I am working on a database gtk3 based program. OS used is Linux Mint 17.3 64-bit and Win 7 64 bit. Issue tested under Python 2.7. I cannot seem to be able to control closing the main window. I want to prevent the window from being closed if there are unsaved changes. I use:

```
self.window.connect("delete-event", self.quit)
```

The "destroy" event seems completely uncontrollable. From what I understand "delete-event" is supposed to be a request, therefore controllable.
So then `self.quit` looks like this:

```
def quit(self, widget, something):
    check_before_quit()
```

So then `check_before_quit()` checks if there are any unsaved changes. Posts the dialog and the main window is still behind. Code is set  to launch `Gtk.main_quit()` if OK is pressed, otherwise just `return`. At this point regardless of whether I press ok/cancel or close the dialog, the main window closes anyway! Same thing happens under Win 7 and Linux.
I have a bind under Ctrl+Q to Quit. This seems to work fine, asks, and correctly quits or stays in the program. So does pressing the close window button somehow overrides something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `delete-event` handler should return `True` or `False`, not do the quitting itself.  It should return `True` if you don't want to close the window, and `False` if you do.  That sounds a little backwards, so I'll word it differently: It should return `True` if you want to stop the signal right there, or `False` if you don't want to do anything about it.